# Export image as encoded geometry path

Tags: c#, image, geometry, drawing

I have to set the Path.Data property of a Shape class. This I believe requires an encoded geometry path for the shape.

Does anyone know of any software that will allow me to design my shape (for example MS Expression Design, Paint.NET, etc) and then be able to extract the encoded geometry path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that Expression Blend can do that.

Comment: Ahhh...Right click -> Path -> Convert to Path.

Thanks